# Postgres db rule to limit records to one record based on a combination of columns values

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

So let's say I have a table with id, foreignId, and status. Is there a way to put a constraint in place to only allow one record for each foreign id where the status is a certain value.

Example:

| id | foreginId | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | started |

Is there a rule I could put in place that wouldn't allow another record of foreignId 1 and status started to be created?

Comment: See `UNIQUE` here [CREATE INDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: Do you mean for specific values of status (eg, `started` & specific other statuses), or just the same values of status? In other words, is `[(2, 2, inprogress), (2, 3, inprogress)]` permitted?

Comment: @AdamKG Right yes exactly what you have there would be permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3).

```
testdb=# create table t(id bigint, foreignid bigint, status text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# create unique index on t(status, foreignid) where status=ANY(ARRAY['started', 'other_status_that_should_be_unique']);
CREATE INDEX
testdb=# insert into t select 1, 1, 'started';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t select 2, 1, 'started';
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t_status_foreignid_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (status, foreignid)=(started, 1) already exists.
testdb=# insert into t select 3, 2, 'started';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t select 4, 3, 'otherstatus';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into t select 5, 3, 'otherstatus';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# select * from t;
 id | foreignid |   status    
----+-----------+-------------
  1 |         1 | started
  3 |         2 | started
  4 |         3 | otherstatus
  5 |         3 | otherstatus
(4 rows)
```